# Enable CSP on 404 page with CI4

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have turned Content Security Policy on in my App.php config file which works fine across all pages of my site. Except I am running a security scanner which detects that on 404 pages it isn't running.

Is there a setting in Codeigniter 4 I need to turn on so that CSP is enabled on 404 pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out if you define your own 404 handler then this problem is automatically resolved.

The solution is to therefore adjust the following in your `Config\Routes.php`

`$routes->set404Override('\App\Controllers\Site::error404');`

Then in your controller create a 404 handling function (I called mine error404). However what is strange is you must **echo** your view and not return it. Not quite sure why but that fixed my problem.